# Read and return values from array with conditions

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I am trying to read from array i created and return value inside array from the column and row its found in.this is what i have at the moment.

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import re

Dir = os.getcwd()
Blks = []

for files in Dir:
    for f in os.listdir(Dir):
        if re.search('txt', f):
            Blks = [each for each in os.listdir(Dir) if each.endswith('.txt')]
print (Blks)

for z in Blks:
    df = pd.read_csv(z, sep=r'\s+', names=['x','y','z'])
    a = []    
    a = df.pivot('y','x','z')
    print (a)
```

OUTPUTS:

```
x       300.00  300.25  300.50  300.75  301.00  301.25  301.50  301.75  
y                                                                        
200.00     100     100     100     100     100     100     100     100   
200.25     100     100     100     100     110     100     100     100   
200.50     100     100     100     100     100     100     100     100
```

x will be my columns and y the rows, inside the array is values corresponding to there adjacent column and row. as you can see above there is a odd 110 value that is 10 above the other values, i'm trying to read the array and return the x (column) and y (row) value for the value that's 10 difference by checking its values next to it(top,bottom,right,left) to calculate the difference.

Hope someone can kindly guide me into right direction, and any beginner tips are appreciated.if its unclear what i'm asking please ask i don't have years experience in all methodology,i have only recently started with python .

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`DataFrame.ix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ix.html) to loop through all the values, row by row and column by column.

```
oddCoordinates=[]

for r in df.shape[0]:
   for c in df.shape[1]:
      if checkDiffFromNeighbors(df,r,c):
         oddCoordinates.append((r,c))
```

The row and column of values that are different from the neighbors are listed in `oddCoordinates`.

To check the difference between the neighbors, you could loop them and count how many different values there are:

```
def checkDiffFromNeighbors(df,r,c):
   #counter of how many different
   diffCnt = 0
   #loop over the neighbor rows
   for dr in [-1,0,1]:
      r1 = r+dr
      #row should be a valid number
      if r1>=0 and r1<df.shape[0]:
         #loop over columns in row
         for dc in [-1,0,1]:
            #either row or column delta should be 0, because we do not allow diagonal
            if dr==0 or dc==0:
               c1 = c+dc
               #check legal column
               if c1>=0 and c1<df.shape[1]:
                  if df.ix[r,c]!=df.ix[r1,c1]:
                     diffCnt += 1

   # if diffCnt==1 then a neighbor is (probably) the odd one
   # otherwise this one is the odd one 
   # Note that you could be more strict and require all neighbors to be different
   if diffCnt>1:
      return True
   else:
      return False
```